# Лямбда-выражение не позволяет изменить переменную

Tags: java, javafx, переменные, lambda

Есть два класса, в основном окне есть кнопка и метка, кнопка запускает метод, который в свою очередь с помощью статического метода другого класса открывает новое окно которому передается String txt, этот txt должен быть изменен в методе второго класса, посредством кнопки, но так как в лямбде можно орудовать только финальными или эффективно-финальными переменными, я создал временную String которую потом пытаюсь присвоить передаваемому значению, но не получается.

```
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    String post = "no changes";
    Label lbl = new Label("no changes");
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            SomeChanger.changeSome(post);
            lbl.setText(post);
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn,lbl);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
public class SomeChanger {
    static String temporarySt = "no changes";
    public static void changeSome(String st){

        //st=temporarySt;
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            temporarySt = "changed st";
            System.out.println("bla");
        });
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.showAndWait();
        st=temporarySt;
    }
}
```

Есть только несколько об'язательных условий которые нельзя изменять:

1. Нестатическая переменная передается статическому методу другого
   класса
2. Метод этого класса должен открывать диалоговое окно.
3. Этот же метод должен посредством кнопки зименить передаваемую переменную так чтобы она изменилась и в первом классе.

Comment: проблема кмк связано не с лямбдами, а с попыткой изменить значение параметра метода (в яве все параметры передаются по значению). Насколько я вижу, `changeSome` завершится только после закрытия окна, поэтому можно просто сделать `return temporarySt` и в вызывающем коде `lbl.setText( SomeChanger.changeSome(post) );`. Вместо статического поля для получения результата из лямбды лучше использовать локальный массив, хотя разница в данном случае не велика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый топорный способ решения - использовать массив из одного элемента.

`final static String[] temporarySt = {"no changes"};`

и потом

```
temporarySt[0] = "changed st";
```

Comment: Не работает, метка на первом окне не изменилась

Comment: Если нужно менять метку - передавайте в changeSome объект Label и вызывайте метод `setText`.
 `public static void changeSome(final Label lbl)`

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам подойдет [StringProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/StringProperty.html)

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ объявите в классе статическую переменную и напремую менять её значение, в данном случае Java не будет ругаться.